# Compile Liferay under os x 10.6

Tags: macos, liferay

Hi i'm trying to build Liferay from source, i've downloaded liferay-portal-src-5.2.3.zip but when i go in and press "ant start" i got 3 errors:

- SampleSQLBuilder.java:139: cannot find symbol > _counter = new SimpleCounter(counterOffset);
- EditServerAction.java:401: cannot find symbol > Log4JUtil.setLevel(loggerName, priority);
- EditUserPortraitAction.java:102: cannot find symbol > PortletRequestUtil.testMultipartWithCommonsFileUpload

I've tried switching compiler using build.properties but nothing seems to work. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I had some conflicts in my classpath. I've cleaned /System/Library/Java/Extension and /Library/Java/Extensions and everything goes right!